# IR Sender Arduino

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide, arduino-c++, infrared

I want so controll my TV with my arduino.
I know that the HEX code for the power button:0xFD020707.
I got a IR sender module: S: Digital3, -:GND, +:5v
This is my code i tryed:

It is not doing anything on the TV and connected a reciver but its just telling 0x0(when hitting a button on the remote it tells the HEX code)

The TV to turn on or the reciver to see the signal

```
``
    #include <IRremote.h>

    IRsend irsender;

    void setup() {
      Serial.begin(9600);
      pinMode(12, OUTPUT);
    }

    void loop() {
      delay(2000);
      digitalWrite(12, HIGH);
      //Power//
      irsender.IRsendNEC(0xFD020707, 32); //Power Code
      Serial.println("Power");
      delay(2000);
      digitalWrite(12, LOW);
    }
``
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the call to `irsender.begin` in setup.  Look at the example codes from the IR library that you are using and see how they call it.

Comment: I will try today I hope it will work

Comment: I tryed so much but nothing is working can you write me a code that is able to send the signal is wrote in the beginning and the signal should be changeable

Comment: I tryed so much but nothing is working can you write me a code that is able to send the signal is wrote in the beginning and the signal should be changeable (if that helps i got a samsung smart tv:TV
Power:  0xFD020707
Volume+:0xF8070707
Volume-:0xF40B0707
Ok:     0x97680707)

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not a free code writing service.  Look at the example codes in the library.  Start by building one of those and get it working.  Then move to trying to control your TV.